# Ошибка - uninitialized constant Devise::Test (NameError) при прохождении теста

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Здравствуйте, при прохождении теста возникает ошибка uninitialized constant Devise::Test (NameError).
В файл spec_hepler и rails_helper добавил строчки:

```
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
```

Тест:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
RSpec.describe CommentsController do

describe "create action" do
@user = User.where(email: "123123@test.com")
sign_in @user

it "redirect to place_path if place is save" do
  post :create, comment: { body: "Comment test body", user_id: 1 }
  response.should redirect_to place_path(assigns(:comment))
end

it "redirect to rot_path if validation fail" do
  post :create, comment: { body: "", user_id: 1 }
  response.should redirect_to root_path
end

end
end
```

Rspec - 3.4.4

Devise - 4.1.0

spec_helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
  expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
 end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Выложите `spec_helper` и `rails_helper`. Скорее всего, внутри теста ничего неизвестно о Devise

Comment: А какая версия `Rspec` и `devise`?

Comment: + В спеки актуального `RSpec`'а, вроде, инклудят `rails_helper` а не `spec_helper`.

Comment: [В Devise 4.1 нет такого модуля.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/4-1-stable#test-helpers) **Читайте документацию**, причём **именно к вашей версии**.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Напишите ответ, если разобрались. Хотя я не очень верю, что он кому-то, кроме вас, поможет .-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку исправил использовав [документацию](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/4-1-stable#test-helpers), для нужной версии Devise.

Строчки в speck_helper:

```
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
```

Заменил на:

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view
```

Так же в самом тесте

```
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
```

Заменил на

```
  include Devise::TestHelpers
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/83640)

Comment: @Alex поправил)